# Setting specific Routing Key to all Receive Endpoints in MassTransit

Tags: c#, .net-core, masstransit

I have a microservice which has over 15 consumers. I would like to know if it is possible to set a RoutingKey for all of the receive endpoints without manually configuring each of them please.

I tried to use AddConfigureEndpointsCallback but I cannot see how to implement this.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Answering it here as someone else might find it useful:

```
config.AddConfigureEndpointsCallback((name, receiveEndpointConfig) =>
{
     if (receiveEndpointConfig is not IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator rabbitMqConfigurator)
     {
         return;
     }

     rabbitMqConfigurator.Bind(name, callback =>
     {
         callback.RoutingKey = "your-routing-key";
     });
 });
```